# Solve: $\arg(z+5+i5\sqrt{3})=\frac{\pi}{6}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

My attempt:

$z=x+iy$

$\arg(x+iy+5+i5\sqrt{3})=\frac{\pi}{6}$

$\arg((x+5)+i(y+5\sqrt{3}))=\frac{\pi}{6}$

$(x+5)+i(y+5\sqrt{3}) = r\operatorname{cis}(\frac{\pi}{6})$

From here, where do I go? I need to remove the "$r$" somehow.

Comment: The solution is not unique, $\,z = r \,\text{cis}\left(\pi/6\right) - 5(1+i\sqrt{3})\,$ will work for any $\,r \gt 0\,$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you first learn about complex numbers, it is very tempting to always substitute $z=x+iy$ to solve problems. That technique has its place, but makes things difficult more often than you might think. Instead, you should try to hang on to the single complex variable $z$ whenever possible.

In this case, I would think geometrically. We are told that the number $z+5+i5\sqrt3$ has a certain argument. That means it must lie on a certain ray out from the origin. And if $z+5+i5\sqrt3$ lies on some ray from the origin, then $z$ must lie on a certain ray that starts at $-5-i5\sqrt3$.

That being said, in your solution, you don't get rid of the $r$. It parametrizes this ray, and each positive real number you insert for it will give you a new solution.

Comment: +1 for spelling it out: "*you should try to hang on to the single complex variable $z$ whenever possible*". That's sound advice which remains untold too often.

Comment: @dxiv I did have to figure it out myself the hard way. And I suspect it's the kind of advise you don't really appreciate until you've done so far that you would've figured it out anyway. But it's worth a shot.

Comment: Parametrizes? Do you mean that if I substitute a value for "$r$", I will obtain a point on the ray? However, aren't there infinite possible "$r$" values for $r>0$?

Comment: @ShootingStars Indeed there are. Just as there are infinitely many possible points on a ray.

Answer (score 0):

At the point where you reached $ \ \arg( \ (x+5)+i(y+5\sqrt3) \ ) \  = \ \frac{\pi}{6} \ \ , \ $ rather than attempt to introduce a polar variable, one could take the tangent of both sides of the equation to deduce
$$  \tan [ \ \arg( \ (x + 5) + i(y + 5\sqrt3) \ ) \ ] \ \ = \ \ \tan \left( \frac{\pi}{6} \right) \ \ = \ \ \frac{1}{\sqrt3}   $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{y \ + \ 5\sqrt{3}}{x \ + \ 5} \ \ = \ \ \frac{1}{\sqrt3} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \  \sqrt3·y \ + \ 15 \ \ = \ \ x \ + \ 5 \ \ , \ \ x \ \neq \ -5  $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ x \ - \ \sqrt3·y \ - \ 10 \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ , \ \ x \ \neq \ -5 \ \ , $$

giving us the equation of a straight line, omitting the point $ \ ( \ -5 \ , \ \frac{15}{-\sqrt3} \ = \ -5 \sqrt3 \ ) \ \ . $  Since the specified argument is $ \ \frac{\pi}{6} \ \ , \ $ we only want the ray extending "to the right and upward" from the "deleted endpoint" $ \ ( \ -5 \ , \  -5 \sqrt3 \ ) \ \ . $

[image]